# Not getting popup in angular6 project

Tags: angular6

I am doing project in angular6. I have put "openModal" button. After clicking on that button popup need to be show. But I am not getting popup. But data which suppose to display on popup will getting display on same page. I am not getting where I have done mistake. Please anyone help me to find, where I have done mistake.
Here I have attached screenshot of output which I am getting.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruvhJ.jpg

Here is my code

app.component.html

```
<button (click)="openModal()">Open Dialog</button>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog, MatDialogConfig } from '@angular/material';
import { MyDialogComponent } from './my-dialog/my-dialog.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';

  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) { }

  openModal() {
    console.log("calling");
    const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();

    dialogConfig.disableClose = true;
    dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;
    dialogConfig.data = {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Angular For Beginners'
    };

    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(MyDialogComponent, dialogConfig);

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      alert("response: " + result)
    });
  }
}
```

my-dialog.component.html

```
   <p>
      my-dialog works!
    </p>
```

my-dialog.component.ts

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material';
import {MatSelectModule} from '@angular/material/select';
import {FormControl, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material'

export interface Staff {
  name: string;

}


@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-dialog',
  templateUrl: './my-dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-dialog.component.css']
})
export class MyDialogComponent  {


   modalTitle: string;

  constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) {
    this.modalTitle = data.title;
    console.log(data)
   }

  staffControl = new FormControl('', [Validators.required]);
  selectFormControl = new FormControl('', Validators.required);

}
```

Comment: Did you got any error in console .

Comment: I didn't add angular material pre-built theme, So I didn't get popup. But now it's working. Please give me any suggestion regarding how can we pass form values to the popup after clicking on submit using angular6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add in your module 
entrycomponent:[yourdailogComponent]

and import css in your style.css  
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';

```
  openHashTagDialog() {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(AddHashTagdialogComponent, {
      data: '',
      width: '400px'
    });
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      this.fetchHashTagsList();
    });
  }
```